# Why is the verb 変えれない instead of 変えられない

Tags: grammar, colloquial-language, contractions

the only two reasons I can think of are politeness(he is talking to himself) or because it might be confused with the passive(because it's potential)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140057/discussion-on-question-by-walid-banana-why-is-the-verb--instead-of-).

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/36120/9831

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is called [ら抜き言葉](https://www.nihongo-c.jp/blog/blog-entry-139.html), 'words without ら', and while it is often used informally by younger speakers, it's non-standard and therefore can make you look sloppy if you use it in a formal environment. It can apply to any 一段 verb, so long as you can use the potential with it: いれる, 見れる, 変えれる, 食べれる etc. Note that when an  一段 ～られる is passive rather than potential you cannot remove ら.

It most likely arose because, for 五段 verbs ending in ～る, 「～れる」 *is* the standard potential form, plus it creates a distinction between the passive and potential forms.

Comment: And it saves energy.